# In Shiny using sortable package drag and drop names that become Charts

Tags: r, shiny, sortablejs

This is my shiny app using the sortable package for drag and drop:

```
library(shiny)
library(imola)
library(sortable)

line_chart <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_line()
bar_chart <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_col()

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    "

    body{
    padding:1em;background: #e7e7e9;
    }

    .default-sortable .rank-list-item{
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: unset;

    }


    .default-sortable.bucket-list.bucket-list-vertical {
    flex-direction: row;
    }

div#rank-list-rank_list_1{
flex-direction: column;
 order: 1;

}

div#rank_list_1 {
    display: flex;


    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px !important;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 5px solid;
}

div#rank-list-rank_list_2{
order:-1;
}

div#rank_list_2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
    gap: 3em;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1em;
}

div#rank_list_2 .rank-list-item {
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 250px;
}
    "
  ),

  title = "Dashboard",
  style = '',
# -  - -- -  - -- -  - -- -  - -- -  - -- -  - -- -  - -- -  - -- -  - -- -  - --
    div(h5('Dashboard',
           style = 'font-size:3em;font-weight:900; text-align: center;'),
        class = 'all_options',
        style  ='height: 100%;border:2px solid gray',
        bucket_list(
          header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
          group_name = "bucket_list_group",
          orientation = "vertical",
          add_rank_list(
            text = NULL,
            input_id = "rank_list_1",
            labels = list(
              htmltools::tags$div(
                "Line Chart"
              ),
              htmltools::tags$div(
                "Bar Chart"
              ),
              htmltools::tags$div(
                "Pie Chart"
              )    
            )
          ),

          add_rank_list(
            text = NULL,
            labels = NULL,
            input_id = "rank_list_2"
          )
        )),

# verbatimTextOutput(outputId = 'tabsetPanels'),
# htmlOutput(outputId = 'tabsetPanels2'),
# verbatimTextOutput(outputId = 'tabsetPanels3')

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is what I need:

The right column have the lists of the charts names that I want to drag e display on the left column.

In others words the right column are the names of the charts and the left column, once I move the name element to the left column appears the line chart (a ggplot chart, for example).

Once I move the "Line Chart" element to that area I would like to display the ggplot line chart there.

The output Should be something like this:

[image]

Any help guys?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it wiht a bit of `css`. Idea is that your movable items are both, the label **and** the plot, but depending on the bucket, you just show the one or the other.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(sortable)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mdat <- mtcars %>% 
   count(cyl) %>% 
   mutate(cyl = factor(cyl))

charts <- tribble(
   ~ id,   ~label,      
   "dots", "Scatter Plot", 
   "bar",  "Bar Chart",  
   "pie",  "Pie Chart"
) %>% 
   mutate(
      plot = list(
         ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point(),
         ggplot(mdat, aes(cyl, n)) + geom_col(),
         ggplot(mdat, aes(x = "", y = n, fill = cyl)) + 
            geom_col(width = 1, color = "white") +
            coord_polar("y", start = 0) + 
            theme_void()
      )
   )

css <- HTML("
#src .plot-container {
   display: none;
}

#sink .label-container {
   display: none;
}
")

make_item <- function(id, label, ...) {
   tagList(
      div(label, class = "label-container"),
      div(plotOutput(id), class = "plot-container")
   )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
   singleton(tags$head(tags$style(css))),
   fluidRow(
      bucket_list(
         header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
         group_name = "bucket_list_group",
         orientation = "vertical",
         add_rank_list(
            text = NULL,
            labels = NULL,
            input_id = "sink",
            css_id = "sink"
         ),
         add_rank_list(
            text = NULL,
            labels = pmap(charts, make_item),
            input_id = "src",
            css_id = "src"
         )
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   for (id in charts$id) {
      ## local construct is needed otherwise we get 3 times the last plot (lazy evaluation)
      local({
         mid <- id
         output[[mid]] <- renderPlot(
            charts %>% filter(id == mid) %>% pull(plot) %>% first(),
            height = 400)
         ## need to switch suspended flag (does not update hidden elements)
         outputOptions(output, mid, suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
      })
   }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Two items, one showing only the labels the other only the plots.]